# What happens on this my declaration?

Tags: perl, oop

I know the title sounds funny, but I found this snippet somewhere:

```
my MyPackage $p1 = MyPackage->new;
```

What role does the name of the package serve in front of `$p1`?

EDIT: I'm running perl `5.10.1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html:

> my TYPE EXPR : ATTRS
>
> A my declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or eval. If more than one value is listed, the list must be placed in parentheses.
>
> *The exact semantics and interface of TYPE and ATTRS are still evolving. TYPE is currently bound to the use of fields pragma, and attributes are handled using the attributes pragma, or starting from Perl 5.8.0 also via the Attribute::Handlers module.*

Comment: I'm doing this in Perl5. Is it something new?

Comment: This aspect of Perl6 has been made available in 5.10. It won't work in 5.8 and earlier.

Comment: The syntax has been available since 5.8.0 -- it just doesn't do anything very useful in 5.8. It also doesn't do anything very useful in 5.10 ;)

Comment: my Dog $spot has been around since 5.005 when it was brought in to allow typed lexicals but never really did anything.  All it did was try to optimize pseudo-hashes, and if you don't know what pseudo-hashes are consider yourself lucky.  These days the only thing "my Class $obj = Class->new" does is tell you the author used to use pseudo-hashes.

Answer (score 12):

It checks for a package with the same name, and, as of now, is tied to the [`fields`](http://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html) pragma which helps check for typos in field names.

For example:

```
package MyPackage;
use fields qw/ foo bar /;
sub new { fields::new(shift) }
```

Then if you try to run

```
use MyPackage;
my MyPackage $p1 = MyPackage->new;
print $p1->{notpresent}, "\n";
```

you get

```
No such class field "notpresent" in variable $p1 of type MyPackage at ...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Nothing to do with Perl 6.  "Restricted hashes" replaced pseudo-hashes, but they're rarely seen these days.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use by fields, the lexical type is used by the experimental [types pragma](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/types) (available from CPAN).